# What is meant by 'The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following Action method:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm=null, int page = 1)
        {
            var racks = repository.AllFindRacks(searchTerm).OrderBy(a=>a.Technology.Tag).ToPagedList(page, 5) ;

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                return PartialView("_RackTable", racks);
            }
            return View(racks);
        }
```

And the following Repository method:-

```
public IQueryable<RackJoin> AllFindRacks(string q)
        {
            List<RackJoin> rakjoin = new List<RackJoin>();
            var result = from rack in tms.TMSRacks
           .Include(rack => rack.DataCenter)
           .Include(rack => rack.Zone)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSFirewalls)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMsRouters)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSServers)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSStorageDevices)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSSwitches)
           .Include(rack => rack.Technology)
                         join resource in entities.Resources
                         .Include(a => a.ComponentDefinition)
                           .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization)
                           .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization)
                         on rack.Technology.IT360ID equals resource.RESOURCEID
                         where (q == null || rack.Technology.Tag.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()))
                         select new RackJoin { 
                         Rack = rack,
                         Resource = resource,
                         Customer = resource.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization,
                         Site = resource.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization,
                         Technology = rack.Technology

                         };
            return result;

        }
```

But when i called the Action method i am getting the following exception :-

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233067   Message=The specified LINQ expression contains
>   references to queries that are associated with different contexts.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity   StackTrace:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are joining data from two different contexts: tms and entities.

This is not possible in LINQ as both have their own connection to the database and a completely separate model.

It's not possible for EF to convert this into a SQL statement. (for all it knows, the tables might live in a different database)

You'd need to either move all your entities to a single context or execute both queries separately and then join them in memory. (use the first option if all tables are in the same DB, use the second if you have separate databases)

Comment: Thanks , you are right the join will join data from different databases. As i am having my own database , and a database for a third party application. so it is not possible to join the two databases in any way . so the only possible way is to define separate queries, i think ?

Comment: You can do that, but you first need to get the data from each DB separately. EF really just converts your LINQ in SQL. After you have the data you can join it using a regular LINQ query

Comment: Hi kenneth i want to ask one  question how can i retrieve data from different db if i execute query it will use too much memory and query will be slow